# SAS compress dates display from 20/01/1990 to 20011990

Tags: sas

How do i print out range of dates

```
data alldates ;
  do dt = '28sep2015'd to '31dec2223'd ;
    output ;
  end ;
  format dt DDMMYY9. ;
run ;
```

but without the "/" character , i.e 
from 20/01/1990 to 20011990

Comment: You will have less confusion about which part is the day of the month and which is the month number if you use YYMMDDN8. format instead of DDMMYYN8. format. Plus you get the added benefit that the values will sort naturally when treated as strings or numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DDMMYYN. format.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000590669.htm

```
format dt DDMMYYN. ;
```

Comment: do I have the same function for time format? i.e 20:34:17=> 203417

Comment: Theres probably some analogous format. Search SAS docs for formats by category. The listing helps to determine which you want to use.

Comment: @user3581800 if you can't find an existing format that work you can make one using PROC FORMAT; PICTURE.

Comment: when trying to do so =>                                                                    ******  proc format data=alltime;;
 picture hr(default=6)
    other = '%0H:%0M:%0S';
run;*********   the results look like that =>19600101 , any idea why?

Comment: You have to specify a datatype=time somewhere in there as well.